# Connecting two home routers and change to IP addresses

Tags: router, subnet, ip, dns

Netgear Cable Modem Router 
Connected to Internet
IP 192.168.0.1
DHCP is ON

D-Link Router
This is my wireless router
IP 192.168.100.0
DHCO is OFF

I want to use the D-Link router as my primary router which all devices should connect to this. Reason for this is I am planing to put some controls such as scheduling the Wi-Fi as well as some local computers connected to the network. I want to connect/disconnect the devices using D-Link router which is the main router I am planing to use.

What I have tried so far

1) LAN to LAN connection using a network cable
Works fine. All good but the main router is Netgear which I don't want to because I can't control my devices.

2) LAN (netgear) to WAN (D-Link) connection using a cable.
DHCP is on in both routers.
Works fine and D-Link router is connected to NetGear and internet available. Love this setup.
Issues is the D-Link router ip is 192.168.100.1 so simple devices such as Chromecast can't find this and not able to connect easily unless I manually configure it.

I am not able to change the D-Link IP, Even if I change, it changed back to 192.168.100.1.

What I want to do is set up a network as below:

NetGear Router will have the IP range 192.168.100.0 to  192.168.100.5 (only my D-Link router will connect to this) DHCP ON

Use a Lan(NetGear) to Wan(Dlink) connection

D-Link router should has standard home IP range 192.168.0.1 to 99.

How can I do this setup ? Please can you tell me all the details such as IP/DNS/SUBNETMASK etc details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your netgear cable modem to bridge mode.

Here is a link that covers the subject:
[bridge mode](http://kb.netgear.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/110/~/when-to-put-modem-into-bridge-mode)

Connect WAN port of d-link router to LAN side of netgear. Your d-link is then authenticating directly to your ISP. Connect all of your computers to the LAN side/wireless side of your d-link.

The only question at this point is one of authentication. You didn't mention if you are utilizing PPPoE, MAC authentication, Etc. If you are utilizing PPPoE then enter your credentials into your d-link router. If you are utilizing MAC authentication you will need to enter the MAC address of your netgear modem into your d-link.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks.. this seem interesting. I think netgear is using PPPoE authentication. I will try this today and post back the results. Thanks

Comment: I've tried this and all works well. Netgear is in bridge mode and D-Link Dir880L router is the main router controls all my devices. THank you.